# Splitting Multiple of delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server, delimiter

I'm looking to split these types of string value in MS SQL Server. The number of characters in groups can vary but there will always be a period "." between the groups:

```
SELECT 'XXX xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx-xxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx' AS StringValue
UNION ALL
SELECT 'xxx xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx-xxx_xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx'
UNION ALL
SELECT '123 INTERSTITIAL.1234.123.ABC.1234.123-ABC.1234.ABCDE01.1234.ABC‌​.1234'
```

There will always be 11 groups between all the characters. I got the first 3 groups broken out but have problems with groups 4 - 10.

Comment: I'm seeing X's.  Can you show us real sample data and what output you want?  Also, which database are you using, as the answer (if possible) would probably be highly DB-specific.

Comment: Welcome to SO; Please provide some details: examples, expected results, database and etc. to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ;).

Comment: Is that a single string? Also explain what is the logic for the splitting.

Comment: Sorry i'm not able to show real data due to other reasons but each section should be broken out into is own field.
XXX xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx-xxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx

1 - XXX xxxxxxxxxxxx
2 - xxxx
3 - xxx
4 -xxx
5 - xxxx
6 - xxx-xxx
7 - xxxx
8 - xxxxxxx
9 - xxxx
10 - xxxx
11 - xxxx

Comment: Which DB engine are you using? MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostGres...?

Comment: if you can't Show real data, Show fake data in the same Format. also make it more clear what the delimiter is in your question, please.

Comment: MS SQL Server is what i'm using

Comment: 123 INTERSTITIAL.1234.123.ABC.1234.123-ABC.1234.ABCDE01.1234.ABC.1234  
the delimiter is a period between each section

Comment: Is there a way without using declare or function? Limited on clients DB.

Answer (score 0):

Within MS SQL Server, you can get the following:

```
stringNumber stringValue
------------ ----------------
1            XXX xxxxxxxxxxxx
2            xxxx
3            xxx
4            xxx
5            xxxx
6            xxx-xxx
7            xxxx
8            xxxxxxx
9            xxxx
10           xxxx
11           xxxx
1            xxx xxxx
2            xxxx
3            xxx
4            xxxx
5            xxxx
6            xxx-xxx_xxxxxxx
7            xxxx
8            xxxxxxx
9            xxxx
10           xxx
11           xxxx
1            123 INTERSTITIAL
2            1234
3            123
4            ABC
5            1234
6            123-ABC
7            1234
8            ABCDE01
9            1234
10           ABC??
11           1234
```

by running the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.fn_SplitString') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitString];
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitString] (
    @string AS VARCHAR(8000)
    ,@stringSeperator AS CHAR(1)
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

SELECT (number - 1) - LEN(REPLACE(LEFT(@string, number - 1), @stringSeperator, '')) + 1 AS stringNumber
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@string, number, CHARINDEX(@stringSeperator, @string + @stringSeperator, number) - number))) AS stringValue
FROM (
    SELECT number
    --SELECT *
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE type = 'p'
    ) AS numbers
WHERE number <= LEN(@string) + 1
    AND SUBSTRING(@stringSeperator + @string, number, 1) = @stringSeperator;
GO

SELECT stringNumber, stringValue
FROM (
    SELECT 'XXX xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx-xxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx' AS Input
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'xxx xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx-xxx_xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '123 INTERSTITIAL.1234.123.ABC.1234.123-ABC.1234.ABCDE01.1234.ABC‌​.1234'
    )OPdata
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_SplitString](Input,'.');
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.fn_SplitString') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Declare @temp TABLE (id INT IDENTITY,String nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT 'XXX xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx-xxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx' UNION
SELECT 'xxx xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx-xxx_xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx'

 SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()OVER(PARTITION BY id Order by id)AS stringNumber    ,
        Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS stringValue
    FROM (
        SELECT id,CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(String, '.', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS String
        FROM @temp
        ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `DECLARE` or `FUNCTION`, you could do the following:

```
SELECT Input
    ,ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Input ORDER BY N)
    ,Item       = SUBSTRING(Input, N, CHARINDEX('.', Input + '.', N) - N)
FROM (
    SELECT 'XXX xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx-xxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx' AS Input
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'xxx xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx-xxx_xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '123 INTERSTITIAL.1234.123.ABC.1234.123-ABC.1234.ABCDE01.1234.ABC‌​.1234'
    ) OPdata
JOIN (
    SELECT TOP (8000)
        n = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM sys.columns a, sys.columns b
    ) n ON SUBSTRING('.' + Input, n, 1) = '.'
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```